Question about "$F$-relatedness"
I'm reviewing the concept of "$F$-relatedness" — Given a smooth map $F\colon M \rightarrow N$, and vector fields $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(N)$, we say that $X$ and $Y$ are $F$-related if $Y \circ F = dF \circ X$— and I see that I have not sufficient examples at hand to show the possible nonuniqueness and possible nonexistence of the pushforward, when $F$ is not a diffeomorphism. Could you provide me with

an example of a vector field $X$ and two different ones $Y$, $Y'$, such that $X$ be $F$-related to $Y$ and $Y'$,
and an example of a vector field which is not $F$-related to anyone?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Are you following a differential geometry book? Which one?

This is not answer as I don't have example, but unless $F$ is a diffeomorphism you cannot call $Y$ the pushforward of $X$, because $F^{-1}$ either does not exist in the category of smooth manifolds. In particular, if $Y$ and $X$ are $F$ related and $F$ is a diffeomorphism then for all $q\in N$ we have that $Y_q=d_{F^{-1}(q)}F(X_{F^{-1}(q)}$. You cannot do this if $F$ is not a diffeomorphism (if it is not bijective then $F^{-1}(q)$ is not unique, and if it is not smooth then this does not define a smooth vector field.

@Chris Yes, I know that, and that's exactly what I would like to illustrate through examples.

@JohnnyLemmon I took the definition from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds book.

I try to give a simple example.
Consider the projection map $$\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y)\mapsto x.$$ You can check that the derivative map $\textrm{d}\pi$ is given by $\textrm{d}\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y)\mapsto x$, where we have used the standard identification between $T \mathbb{R}^2$ ($T \mathbb{R}$) and $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($\mathbb{R}$) which maps $T \mathbb{R}^2  \to \mathbb{R}^2: a \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + b \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \to (a,b)$.

For the vector fields $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Try to imagine what these vector fields look like. You see that $$\textrm{d}\pi(X)= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \textrm{d}\pi(Y). $$ Hence, both the vector fields $X,Y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are $\pi$-related to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the vector field $Z= y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. At a point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we then have $$\textrm{d}\pi_{(a,b)}(Z) = b \frac{\partial}{\partial x}. $$ Consider then for example the points $A=(0, 1)$ and $B=(0, 2)$, then $$\textrm{d}\pi_{A}(Z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \text{ and } \textrm{d}\pi_{B}(Z) = 2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$ Yet, $\pi(A)=\pi(B) = 0$. Hence, there needs to be a vector field $Z'$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that at zero, it is both $2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, which is of course not possible. Hence, the vector field $Z$ is not $\pi$-related to a vector field on $\mathbb{R}$.


Hope this helps!
Edit:
Consider the embedding $\iota: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2:x \mapsto (x,0)$. Then, also $\mathrm{d}\iota(x) = (x,0)$. Take the vector fields $$X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \quad Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \quad Y' = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$ Then you can easily see that both $Y$ and $Y'$ are $\iota$-related to $X$, since you have to evaluate $Y'$ in $\iota(x) = (x,0)$.

The second example is very helpful, thank you. However, I think the first one is not what I asked for. You shared two vector fields that are $\pi$-related to one, and I asked for one vector field that is $F$-related to two different vector fields.

Thanks for letting me know, I just edited my answer! Hope that helps.

Let $U\subset M$ be an open submanifold, and $X$ a vector field with compact support contained in $U$. Let $V$ be another open submanifold disjoint from $U$, and $Z$ and $Z'$ be vector fields with compact support in $V$. We can extend $X$, $Z$, and $Z'$ by zero to the whole of $M$ to obtain global vector fields $\tilde{X}$, $\tilde{Z}$, and $\tilde{Z}'$. Set $Y$ to be $Y=\tilde{X}+\tilde{Z}$ and $Y'=\tilde{X}+\tilde{Z}'$.
Now let $\iota:U\rightarrow M$ be the embedding. The differential is just the identity map, so it is clear that for all $p\in U$ we have that $X_p=\tilde{X}_{\iota(p)}$. Moreover, for all $p\in U$ we have that $Y_{\iota(p)}=Y'_{\iota(p)}=\tilde{X_p}$ as $\tilde{Z}$ and $\tilde{Z}'$ are identically zero on $U$. It follows that $X$ is $\iota$-related to both $Y$ and $Y'$.
If you want two vector fields $X$ and $X'$ which are both $F$ related $Y$, take any fibre bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ over $M$. We have that the $\ker D\pi$ determines a vertical  subbundle $V\subset TE$ which satisfies $(\ker D_p\pi)=T_pE_{\pi(p)}=V_p$ where $E_{\pi(p)}$ is the fiber over $\pi(p)\in M$. Choose a horizontal distribution $H\subset TE$ such that $V\oplus H=TE$. Let $Y$ be a vector field on $M$, then there is a unique horiztonal vector field $X$ on $E$ which is $\pi$ related to $Y$. Now take any vertical vector field $Z$, then $X'=X+Z$ is also $\pi$ related to $Y$ as for all $p\in E$ we have that $D_p\pi(Z_p)=0$, while $D_p\pi(X_p)=Y_{\pi(p)}$.
